# Forget Microsoft account in Windows 10's Outlook

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2016

Even after being removed from Windows 10's Outlook inbox, Microsoft accounts are remembered by the device and can be readded to Outlook without password input (even if the password has been changed)

[image]

How can the computer forget them permanently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Control Panel, Mail, Profiles, and delete the Outlook Profile. Then restart the computer.  You can now add a new Account (in the same place) with a different password.